# how do I get selectedvalues HtmlSelectManyCheckbox? in JSF

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces

I dynamically added HtmlSelectManyCheckbox. And I don't know how to get selected values?

```
HtmlSelectManyCheckbox checkbox = (HtmlSelectManyCheckbox)
                    app.createComponent(HtmlSelectManyCheckbox.COMPONENT_TYPE);

List<SelectItem> checkItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++) {
                checkItems.add(new SelectItem(k));
            }
            UISelectItems selectCheckItems = new UISelectItems();
            selectCheckItems.setValue(checkItems);
            checkbox.getChildren().add(selectCheckItems);
            checkbox.setValue("ssssssssss");
            grid.getChildren().add(checkbox);
```

Is it true for dynamically add HtmlSelectManyCheckbox in JSF? if not please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`getSelectedValues()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html#getSelectedValues()) like so:

```
UISelectMany checkboxParent = (UISelectMany) checkBox;
    Object[] selectedValues = checkboxParent.getSelectedValues();
```